# Google Chart Diagram Changing Heights When Display Toggled

Tags: reactjs, google-visualization

So basically I have 3 diagrams that represent a users spending per month. Using a select onChange handler the diagram for the selected will show and the others will be hidden. The first (default selected) diagram will be perfect height, however the other two diagrams won't.

This is my code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (months.length > 0) {
        let allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".montly-category-spending");
        allDivs.forEach(item => {
            // item.classList.add("d-none"); -------- > LINE A
        });

        let div = document.querySelector("#" + selectedMonth);
        div.classList.remove("d-none");
    }
}, [selectedMonth]);

function drawPieDiagram(id) {
    let div = document.querySelector("#" + id);
    let key = id.replace("-", " ");
    let monthData = monthsData[key];

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');

    data.addRows(
        Object.entries(monthData).map(([key, value]) => [key, value])
    );

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
        'width': 'auto',
        'height': height,
        'title': `Transactions per category (${key})`,
    };

    console.log(options);
    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(div);

    chart.draw(data, options);
}

function handleChange(event) {
    let id = event.currentTarget.value;
    setSelectedMonth(id);
}

return (
    <>
        <div id="google-pie-chart" class="col-12 col-lg-4 p-0">
            {months.map(item => <div id={item} class="montly-category-spending p-0" style={{ height: height }}></div>)}
            <select value={selectedMonth} onChange={handleChange} class="form-select">
                {months.map(item => (
                    <option value={item}>{item.replace('-', ' ')}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>

    </>
);
```

This is how it looks when LINE A is commented [image]

This is how it looks when LINE A isn't commented:

[image]

And when other option is selected:

[image]

The weird thing is that only the first default option works. Also as you can see the height in the element inspector should be 500px everywhere.

I tried multiple small things, like using js to fix the height to be the same as the variable height, but without success. there's some other small things I've tried aswell without any success.

While writing this after a refresh it suddently worked, but after a refresh again it stopped working.

So really I have no clue why this keeps happening, anything is appreciated!

Comment: you need to wait until the chart is selected before drawing for the first time. if you draw the chart while its container is hidden, you will get weird results.